# Conversion between COLORREF and D2D1::ColorF

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi+, direct2d

In my windows desktop application development, both GDI+ and Direct2D are being used for drawing rectangles, lines, ellipses, etc. How do I convert from COLORREF (used in GDI+ for the brush) to D2D1::ColorF (used in Direct2D for the brush) and vice-versa?

**Code Sample:**

In **GDI+**, in order to fill a rectangle with a specific colour,

```
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc;

hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
HBRUSH brush;

brush = ::CreateSolidBrush(*pColor);    //COLORREF* pColor;

::FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, brush);
::DeleteObject((HGDIOBJ) brush);

EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
```

In **Direct2D**, drawing an ellipse with a specific colour,

> ```
> pRenderTarget->BeginDraw(); 
>
> //type ID2D1SolidColorBrush - alpha value (4th parameter) is omitted
> brush->SetColor(D2D1::ColorF(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f));
>
> const D2D1_ELLIPSE circle1 = D2D1::Ellipse(
>               D2D1::Point2F(pt1, pt2, 3.0f, 1.0f);
>
> pRenderTarget->DrawEllipse(circle1, brush);
>
> pRenderTarget->EndDraw();
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are built from three color components: R, G, B.

[`ColorF::ColorF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
ColorF(FLOAT, FLOAT, FLOAT, FLOAT)(
  FLOAT r,
  FLOAT g,
  FLOAT b,
  FLOAT a = 1.0
);
```

[`COLORREF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183449%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> To create a COLORREF color value, use the RGB macro. To extract the individual values for the red, green, and blue components of a color value, use the GetRValue, GetGValue, and GetBValue macros, respectively.

```
COLORREF RGB(
  BYTE byRed,
  BYTE byGreen,
  BYTE byBlue
);
```

Specifically, you can use `GetRValue`, `GetGValue`, and `GetBValue` macros to obtain individual components from `COLORREF` and then use them in the `ColorF` constructor.

Comment: To convert from D2D1::ColorF::ColorF to COLORREF?

COLORREF color = RGB(d2dColor.r, d2dColor.g, d2dColor.b); doesn't work, as they are float AND COLORREF expects RGB as a BYTE via 
RGB(BYTE byRed, BYTE byGreen, BYTE byBlue);

Comment: BYTE components are 0..255, FLOAT ones are 0.0..1.0 - so the math is simple.